# Char.js Interpolation linear

Tags: javascript, interpolation, chart.js

i'm trying to draw functions with Chart.js
I have a problem with my draw let's see :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJRfn.png)

This is the 'x' function and the line isn't straight 
I don't know if it's a problem of resolution or of interpolation 
So here is my chart :

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          datasets: [{
              borderWidth:2,
              pointRadius :0,
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
              label: 'Scatter Dataset',
              data: JSON.parse(data),
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0,
              cubicInterpolationMode: 'linear'

          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  type: 'linear',
                  position: 'bottom'
              }]
          },
          pan: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'xy'
          },
          zoom: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'xy',
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
      }
  });
```

Thx guys

Comment: In `data: { datasets: [{ data: JSON.parse(data)...` what is the value of the `data` variable passed to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: It's just a string as JS object like this : [{ x: 1, y: 1},{ x: 2, y: 2}, { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 4,y:5}, ....... , {x: 100,y: 100}]

here my step is 1

Comment: If the points are linear, then it must be the way `chart.js` is rendering.  First, right above `var scatterChart` add a line `console.log(data);` and add that output to your question so we can see the _true_ `json` that is being parsed.  Next, try hard coding `data: [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:100, y:100 }],` and see if the line looks any better.

Comment: my data var is : "[{ x: -100, y: -100},{ x: -99, y: -99}, { x: -98, y: -98 }, ......, { x: 0,y:0}, ....... , {x: 100,y: 100}]"

And Yes, [{ x:-100, y:-100 }, { x:100, y:100 }] displaying well.
But my problem is that's i'm working on rendering function app.
So i can't do this for a sinus or cosinus function for example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how `chart.js` is drawing the small line segments between data points.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y83sf93/) that animates a full opacity line over top of a lighter line.  The second line is growing at a `step=1` while the lighter line is nice and straight `[{x:-100,y:-100},{x:100,y:100}]`.  If you change to `step=10` you will see the line fill in straight.

In the code below (or in the fiddle) you can play around with changing the `borderWidth`, `borderColor`, and `opacity`.  I tried adding `borderCapStyle: 'round'` and `borderJoinStyle: 'round'`, but neither seemed to have much effect.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");
var i = -100;
var data = [{x: i, y: i}];
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      label: 'Scatter Dataset 1',
      data: data,
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'linear'
    }, {
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)',
      label: 'Scatter Dataset 2',
      data: [{x:-100,y:-100},{x:100,y:100}],
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'linear'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom'
      }]
    },
    pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'xy'
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'xy',
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
  }
});
var step = 1;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  i += step;
  if (i <= 100) {
    scatterChart.data.datasets[0].data.push({x:i,y:i});
    scatterChart.update();
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 200);
```

and

```
<canvas id="test" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```